# Usage of PMAP / Dynamically Loading Libraries (C/Linux)

Tags: c, linux, dynamic, posix, libraries

The following [cat++](https://cnds.jacobs-university.de/courses/os-2019/src/cat++/) program dynamically loads transformations applied to lines before they are printed. After compiling successfully, I run the following command:

`echo "hello world" |./cat++ -l ./librot13.so -l ./libupper.so -l ./librot13.so`

How can I use pmap to check the number of memory segments which are added to the process when 1 of the libraries implementing a transform is being loaded? What PID and command line options am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run 'pmap' on an active process to see the memory segment. The command that was used (`echo ... | cat`) will finish in a fraction of a seconds. Consider instead the delayed version.

```
(echo bar ; sleep 100) | ./cat++ -l ./librot13.so -l ./libupper.so -l ./librot13.so &
# The '$!' will hold the PID of the 'cat++' process.
pmap $!
```

Comment: Can you help me interpret the output according to my question? Since it's different than the examples I have been seeing online. Here's what I get on my terminal:


`00005579a85ab000      8K r-x-- cat++
00005579a87ac000      4K r---- cat++
00005579a87ad000      4K rw--- cat++
00005579a9589000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f0aad8ce000      4K r-x-- libupper.so
00007f0aad8cf000   2044K ----- libupper.so`

and continued...